# Can you have multiple Free Azure App Service Plans to have more than 10 free web apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I was wondering whether you could have more than 1 free Azure App Service Plan so you can have more than 10 free hosted websites per Azure account. Is this possible or are you charged automatically if your Azure account goes over 10 free websites?

Comment: This not the site where you post such question. Its more like for asking technical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Under Free Tier, each App Service Plan can have 10 Web Apps and you can have 10 such App Service Plans in a single region. So you can have host 100 Web Apps for free in a single region.

For more details, please see Azure Web Apps limits here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits.